# Sanitizing whitespace in generated URL parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having an issue with a PHP page that generates an HTML document. On the page, there is a form that has a `<select>` box, and each `<option>` inside has a value with the URL parameters to use when changing the window location when the form is "submitted". The issue is that I noticed is that one of the parameters is a name, and when that name has a space in it, it breaks the window location because the space remains in the URL.

I've tried simply doing a `str_replace()` on the string before it generates the `<option>` tag, and when I view the `<option>` in Firefox' inspector, it DOES contain a `%20` instead of a space, but when I look at the URL bar after clicking the `<option>`, it still retains the space instead of the `%20`. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the following snippet?

```
print("<form name=sel1>");
print("<select size=10 style='width:200;font-family:courier,monospace;
        font-weight:bold;color:black;' ");
print("onchange=\"location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;\">");
for($i = 0; $i < count($allGroups); $i++)
{
    print("<option value='groups.php?action=");
    if($advancedPermissions)
    {
        if($modGroups)
        {
            print("edit");
        }
        else
        {
            print("view");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("edit");
    }
    print("&group_id=");
    print(str_replace(" ", "%20", $allGroups[$i][0])."'>");

    print($allGroups[$i][0]);
    if($allGroups[$i][2] != 'Y')
    {
        print(" - inactive");
    }
}

print("</select></form>");
```

The relevant lines are the line with `location =` and the line just after the `group_id` parameter is added, where the `str_replace()` is done.

I do the `str_replace()` on just the value, not the display text, so it will show normally to the user, but contain the `%20` character for when it is passed to the window location, but regardless, it either ignores it, or something else is happening I am not aware of.

Comment: Use PHP Functions first trim() and then str_replace(" " , "-",$location) , try it !

Comment: @Sanmeet I can't replace it with dashes, as some group IDs have dashes in them. It has to be the %20. But I also have to then remove that %20 if it doesn't do that automatically when the PHP page receives that data, so I can match the group_id parameter to the info coming from the DB.

Comment: Ok ok that's a tough one

Comment: 1. Get rid of that `str_replace()` and use either `urlencode()` or `rawurlencode()`. 2. The URL bar lies, and will almost always show you the decoded, human-friendly version of a URL. 3. The truly correct answer is `http_build_query()` as in miken's example, but it depends on how motivated you are to clean up some of that mess vs throwing your hands in the air and saying "well _I_ didn't write it...".

Comment: @Sanmitch No, I'm definitely gonna try out http_build_query, but I was referring to his suggestion of rewriting the entire page to fit his preferred format. It would be nice, but I don't have the time or the reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code is a whole mess of bad practices. First, separation of code (PHP) and presentation (HTML) is essential for making sense of things. You should be doing logic in a separate code block at the very least, if not a separate file. Definitely not in the middle of an HTML element. Exiting PHP and using [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and [short echo tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) make this separation much clearer.

You should be building HTTP query strings using the [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function, which will handle escaping issues like the one you're having, and you should always escape HTML for output using [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

[`print`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) is not commonly used, but note that it's a language construct and not a function. Parentheses are not needed, and rarely used.

Inline CSS and [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) declarations are very 20th century and should be avoided wherever possible.

Here's how I would start to rework this code...

```php
<?php
// assuming $allGroups is created in a loop
// the following code could be incorporated into that loop
$options = [];
foreach ($allGroups as $group) {
    $action = ($advancedPermissions && !$modGroups) ? "view" : "edit";
    $group_id = $group[0];
    $url = "groups.php?" . http_build_query(compact("action", "group_id"));
    $options[$url] = $group[0] . ($group[4] !== "Y" ? " - inactive" : "");
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #location_select {
            width: 200px; font-family: monospace; font-weight: bold; color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form name=sel1>
        <select id="location_select" size="10">
    <?php foreach ($options as $value => $option): ?>
            <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>">
                <?= htmlspecialchars($option) ?>
            </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
    </form>

    <script>
        document
            .getElementById("location_selector")
            .addEventListener("change", function() {
                window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But if you are looking for the quick fix:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < count($allGroups); $i++)
{
    $action = ($advancedPermissions && !$modGroups) ? "view" : "edit";
    $group_id = $allGroups[$i][0];
    $url = "groups.php?" . http_build_query(compact("action", "group_id"));
    print("<option value='$url'>");
    print($allGroups[$i][0]);
    if($allGroups[$i][2] != 'Y')
    {
        print(" - inactive");
    }
    print("</option>");
}
```

Comment: Well while your comments about the design are nice, this is legacy code I inherited, and I am just trying to implement a new feature. I don't have time to be refactoring the entire website. The page needs to be generated dynamically because what's on the page depends on DB data and URL parameters. I'll give http_build_query and htmlspecialchars a try.

Comment: Well the minimal fix would be taking the first 3 lines of my loop and using it at the top of your loop to properly build the URL. I've updated my answer to include that. `htmlspecialchars()` is unlikely to make a difference with the specific problem you're having, but is obviously recommended by best practices.

Comment: Turns out that the space in the group ID wasn't the problem... I noticed I had a logical condition which causes the page to not construct the info view, and I couldn't remember for what purpose I put that there, but basically, any group ID with a space in it would cause it to stop page construction. Not sure why I did that, but... oh well, it works now. Thanks!